# How to find all files with the same extension within a directory in parallel

Tags: find

I want to grep files with a specific extension. I know how to do it using find command as blow:

```
find . -type f -name "*.pptx"
```

I am wondering if I can do above command in **parallel** (using more CPU).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find`-ception:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -print0 | xargs -0 -L1 -P0 -i find {} -type f -name '*.pptx'
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.pptx'
```

- `-maxdepth 1` `-mindepth 1` restricts the search to the immediate contents of the directory. We look up all the subdirectories (`-type d`).
- Then we use [`xargs`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/xargs.1) to run `find` on all the subdirectories. `-0` in combination with `-print0` takes care of any special characters that may occur in filenames.
- `-P0` tells `xargs` to run as many `find`s as possible in parallel. You can restrict it to run at most N processes using `-PN`.
- Lastly, since we have run `find` on all subdirectories, we finally run a `find` on the current directory as well (and only on the current directory - hence `-maxdepth 1`).

---

Word of caution: `find` is likely to be IO-intensive. There's only so much benefit you can get from running multiple instances in parallel.
Also, the output of the many `find`s may get jumbled together, thus reducing the usefulness of this approach.